# Liferay 7 Taglib issue with new module in Dev Studio

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-ide

I just started with a fresh Dev Studio Installation on Windows 10.

I installed the Liferay workspace from installer.

After that I created a new Liferay Module Project as described here: https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360032887652-Creating-the-Web-Project.

The Module is available and starts in the portal.

But I did not get the taglibs working. Warning in view.jsp: The tag handler class for "liferay-ui:message" (com.liferay.taglib.ui.MessageTag) was not found on the Java Build Path

Nethertheless, the Strings from Language.properties are not there. Only the key will be shown.

Can anyone help here?

Thanks,

Christian

The taglibs are correctly imported in the init.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>

<liferay-theme:defineObjects />

<portlet:defineObjects />
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.api"
    

    cssBuilder group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.css.builder", version: "3.0.3"
}
```